# Problem while running SQL Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, ssms

I install the MS SQL Management Studio 2008, the installation was successfull but when i run the Management Studio and connect to any Server (diffrent Servers in diffrent locations) I got following error

> ************** Ausnahmetext **************
>   System.TypeLoadException: Der Typ "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ISfcDomainLite" in der Assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" konnte nicht geladen werden.
>      bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItem.get_State()
>      bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.LazyTreeView.AdjustStateHealthStatus(TreeNode inputNode)
>      bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.LazyTreeView.AddIconToImageMap(TreeNode node)
>      bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.LoadNodeValuesFromItem(INavigableItem containedItem)
>      bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.AddedToTree()
>      bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.LazyTreeView.AddNodesInternal(TreeNode source, TreeNode[] nodesToAdd)

Any suggestions to solve this Problem? The System is Win7x64.

Regards
Rene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for that late answer. I had this problem, too. And I could solve it - not by reinstallation of the OS :-)

**Problem description:**
The problem occured, because I made an installation of "sql server express 2008 R2". Don't ask why, I thought it was a good idea. But SQL Management Server 2008 R2 did'nt worked. So I uninstalled the whole R2-SQL Server and installed a early "SQL Server 2008 express advanced edtion". SQL Server worked, but Management Studio throught that exception (s.a.).

**The Solution:**
The Problem is, the there are rests of the SQL Server R2 installation. Some assemblies are newer. 
Note: for the following solution I will not garantee, that it works nor that your system will work properly after it.
 **USE IT ON YOUR OWN RISK!**

So do the following steps:

1. Uninstall all "Microsoft SQL Server 2008" entries with the standard uninstall-page (System > Programs > uninstallation, in german: "Systemsteuerung > Programme > Programm deinstallieren").
   Also uninstall the entry "Support for SQL Server Setup" (german: "Unterstützung für SQL Server Setup")
2. Now, if you - like me - have problems to uninstall the SQL Server entries, then download the microsoft tool [Windows Installer clean up](http://www.pcwelt.de/downloads/Windows-Installer-CleanUp-Utility-557997.html). After starting it, you will get a list of the setups. These setups can be cleaned up with this tool.
3. So, we have to get rid of the R2 assemblies. Open explorer and navigate to "C:\Windows\assembly". Find the entries starting with "Microsoft.SqlServer". Select them all and press "delete". If there comes a message, that not all could be deleted, then you missed an installation in step 2!
4. Now you can install "SQL Server 2008 express". I used the x86 installation without ServicePack.